# Java TextArea Get Possible Amount of Characters at Line

Tags: java, textarea, character, line, sizeof

I would like to know if its possible to know how many characters a line can have programatically. I already searched but didn't found any useful..

Basically I want to fill a line with the same character, but just one entire line.

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could instead use a JTextField like so...

```
 JTextField text_field = new JTextField(25);
```

Here you can see we've preset the field to be able to hold up to a maximum of 25 characters

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I am using TextArea and thats how it should be. I am appending text to it, and want to make a separator with symbols, but just want to fill a line not more. I can do this, manually counting, but if user makes the textArea larger, it will not work afterwards lol.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , I don't want to force the user to not be able to resize :/
If there is any solution, I would like to know :)

Comment: I'm going to assume your using a Swing GUI. If so, what layout(s) are you using?

Comment: I have an text area inside jpanel :)

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, but perhaps one of these

```
getColumns()
getColumnWidth()
getRows()
getRowWidth()
```

will work?
If you want to fill the line, just use a for loop and the insert(str, index) method.

Comment: I don't have getRowWidth(), only have getRows() and getColumns(), thanks in advance!

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html says it exists, perhaps you're not using the correct version? Does getColumns or getRows work for you?

Comment: I am using TextArea not TextField mate, its different . Thanks for your reply anyway ;)